# Ambari Hortonworks Installation fails at step "Install, Start and Test"

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am installing ambari hortonworks on CentOS 6. I have a local repo set up. Two data nodes and one master/name node are running. The ambari server is running on master.Now my issue is installation fails for random reasons at step "Install, Start and Test". one or more node randomly fails for reasons like failed to install service (hdp slecect,hive,hadoop) when i hit retry some nodes fails in other combination. I am missing something ???

Comment: Do you have passwordless SSH setup? The YUM repositories between all the machines are the same? Can you SSH into the machines yourself and run the commands that the Ambari logs mention?

Comment: You need to give us more information. Can you share the logs that describe exactly what's failing?

Comment: screenshot would be great. Do service logs mention command timeout?